# How do I move one position backwards so that my new element is not on top of my previous one?

Tags: python, arrays, queue

How do I move one position backwards so that my new element is not on top of my previous one? This is a queue.
This is the constructor:

```
def _init_(self, capacity=8):
    self.__data = [None] * capacity
    self.__front = 0
    self.__size = 0
```

This is the function with problems:

```
def insert_p_clients(self, client):
        if self.is_full():
            raise ValueError('A fila está cheia! Tente mais tarde!')
        self._data[self._front] = client
        self._front = (self.front + 1) % len(self._data)
        self.__size += 1
```

Comment: There are a number of missing underscores in the code as given.

Answer (score 0):

In the code as given, there are a number of missing underscores, starting with the `__init__()` method. The following version of `insert_p_clients()` should work:

```
    def insert_p_clients(self, client):
        if self.is_full():
            raise ValueError('A fila está cheia! Tente mais tarde!')
        self.__data[self.__front] = client
        self.__front = (self.__front+1) % len(self.__data) 
        self.__size += 1
```

I've tested this with a significant amount of scaffolding and it all seems to work.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, capacity=8):
        self.__data = [None] * capacity
        self.__front = 0
        self.__rear = 0
        self.__size = 0

    def is_full(self):
        return self.__size >= len(self.__data)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.__size <= 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__size

    def capacity(self):
        return len(self.__data)

    def insert_p_clients(self, client):
        if self.is_full():
            raise ValueError('A fila está cheia! Tente mais tarde!')
        self.__data[self.__front] = client
        self.__front = (self.__front+1) % len(self.__data) 
        self.__size += 1
    

    def remove_p_client(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise ValueError('A fila está vazia!')
        self.__data[self.__rear] = None
        self.__rear = (self.__rear + 1) % len(self.__data)
        self.__size -= 1
    
    
    def get_queue_front(self):
        return self.__data[self.__front-1]

    
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.__size == 0:
            return str([])
        result = list()
        index = self.__rear
        while ((index % len(self.__data)) != self.__front):
            result.append(self.__data[(index % len(self.__data))])
            index += 1
        return str(result)
    
            
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue(4)
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    try:
        q.remove_p_client()
    except:
        print("Queue is empty.")
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(13)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(17)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.remove_p_client()
    except:
        print("Queue is empty.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(23)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(42)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(57)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.insert_p_clients(69)
    except:
        print("Queue is full.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
    try:
        q.remove_p_client()
    except:
        print("Queue is empty.")
    print(q.get_queue_front())
    print(q)
    print(repr(q))
    print(len(q))
```